Expo GO, problema para ejecutar
¿Por qué al ejecutar expo, me dice que cree un archivo index, pero ya lo tengo dentro de /app?, este es el mensaje:
Welcome to expo
Start by creating a file in the C:\projects\fedecamaras-hamal\AsambleaAnualFedecamaras\app directory
touch C:\projects\fedecamaras-hamal\AsambleaAnualFedecamaras\app/index.js
